# Почему ничего не меняется через ftp opencart?

Tags: opencart, ftp

Через ftp в меняю что либо (например в header.twig пишу 123). В админке очищаю весь кэш. Но на сайте нет изменений. НО, если перейти в раздел Дизайн > Редактор шаблона > header.twig я вижу эти 123. Нажимаю кнопку сохранить, и только тогда на сайте видны изменения

Answer (score 0):

После редактирования twig шаблона нужно:

1. обновить кеш модификаторов
2. обновить кеш twig